# How to set a color to marked messages in Claws Mail?

Tags: claws-mail

I'm using Claws Mail version 3.9.3. Is there a way to set a color to marked messages in the message list?

Comment: I haven't actually found a way. Maybe setting the marked icon to something more visible could work.

Comment: Your question has been flagged as low quality (not by me) as it lacks the detail for us to provide a good answer. Please see [ask] and take our [tour].